# Show repo commits on click using github API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, api, github

I am playing with the Github API and AngularJS and I would like to show the commits of a repo on clicking the name of the repo I pulled from a user

Here is the html I have now:

```
<ul ng-repeat="repo in repos">
    <li><a href="{{repo.html_url}}" target="_blank"> {{repo.name}} </a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the function pulling this:

```
function GithubController($scope, $http) {
   $scope.getInfo = function () {
     $scope.userNotFound = false;
     $scope.loaded = false;

     $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username)
           .success(function (data) {
              if (data.name == "") data.name = data.login;
              $scope.user = data;
              $scope.loaded = true;
           })
           .error(function () {
              $scope.userNotFound = true;
           });
     $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username + "/repos").success(function (data) {
        $scope.repos = data;
        $scope.reposFound = data.length > 0;
     });
  }
}
```

I know I will need to probably use Jquery to populate the DOM on click of the li element, but I am not sure where to start.

Here is a link to the commit page for the Github API:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

Comment: You will not need jQuery to populate the DOM, please create a fiddle with what you have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the repository, you can get commits like this:

```
$scope.getCommits = function(repo) {
  $http.get("https://api.github.com/repositories/" + repo.id + "/commits").success(function(data) {
    repo.commits = data;
  })
}
```

You don't need jQuery to display them.  Here is a quick example of how you could list them using a nested `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul ng-repeat="repo in repos">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a ng-click="getCommits(repo)"> {{repo.name}} </a>
      <div class="well">{{repo.name}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="commit in repo.commits">
            <div><pre>{{commit | json}}</pre></div>        
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a working demo:  http://plnkr.co/eWDT8xsssv5ofQJ8YjiJ

Note - some requests produce a `409 (Conflict)` response.  I'm not sure why.  And some repositories only have one commit.  So you might have to click a few to find one with multiple commits.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I needed. For the 409 I have it print 'No  Repos Found'